# Not found for some routes

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with some of my routes in Laravel. this my code in web.php file:

```php
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware' => ['auth:web']], function () {
    Route::get('/admin/audio/create/{audio?}', 'AdminAudioController@create')->name('admin.audioCreate');
    Route::get('/admin/article/create/{article?}', 'AdminArticleController@create')->name('admin.articleCreate');
}
```

and this my link in blade

```html
<a href="{{ route('admin.audioCreate' , ['audio' => $audio->audioId]) }}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>    
<a href="{{ route('admin.articleCreate' , ['article' => $article->articleId]) }}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
```

and this are my Controllers:
AdminAudioController

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Article;
use App\Http\Requests\ArticleRequest;

class AdminArticleController extends AdminController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $articleList = Article::where('removed', false)->latest()->paginate(10);
        return view('admin.article.archive', compact('articleList'));
    }

    public function create(Article $article = null)
    {
        return view('admin.article.create', compact('article'));
    }
}
```

AdminArticleController

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Article;
use App\Http\Requests\ArticleRequest;

class AdminArticleController extends AdminController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $articleList = Article::where('removed', false)->latest()->paginate(10);
        return view('admin.article.archive', compact('articleList'));
    }

    public function create(Article $article = null)
    {
        return view('admin.article.create', compact('article'));
    }
}
```

but my second link with name "admin.articleCreate" doesn't work and get "404 not found" what should I do?

and this is my article model

```
class Article extends Model
{
protected $primaryKey = 'articleId';

use Sluggable;

protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'subTitle1', 'subTitle2',
    'image',
    'description',
    'body',
    'enable',
];

protected $casts = [
    'image' => 'array'
];

/**
 * Return the sluggable configuration array for this model.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function sluggable(): array
{
    return [
        'slug' => [
            'source' => 'title'
        ]
    ];
}

public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
}
```

Comment: Your code seems ok to me, maybe you have cached routes. Try executing: `php artisan route:cache`

Comment: What the content of `$article->articleId` in your link? I presume you have a value that's not found in your articles table

Comment: it's Id's record, when click on link it goes to link "http://localhost:8000/admin/article/create/1" but doesn't show my view and get 404 and courect link goes to "http://localhost:8000/admin/audio/create/10" and it's work corectly

Comment: I will assume that this article **exists** on your table. Is `articleId`a custom primary key that replace `id` ?

Comment: And if that so, It could be that your model `Article` is missing `protected $primaryKey = 'articleId';`

Comment: That's because of `getRouteKeyName` the model binding relate on that. Use `['article' => $article->slug]` instead on your link. If it's working, I will make as answer to close the question

Comment: I add my model to end of question. I put protected $primaryKey = 'articleId';  in my model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the method `create(Article $article = null)` on your controller, Laravel uses [**Model Binding**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding) to resolve your model and the model binding uses the method you have added to your model

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug'; // by default it will be $primaryKey which is 'id'
}
```

In short, Laravel will try to use `slug` to **find** your model while your giving him `articleId`

So to fix it you have few options

- Using the slug in the URL (the one I would recommend)

```
// blade.php
<a href="{{ route('admin.articleCreate' , ['article' => $article->slug]) }}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
```

- Using the primary articleId in the URL

```
// blade.php
<a href="{{ route('admin.articleCreate' , ['article' => $article->articleId]) }}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>

// Article.php.php
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'articleId'; 
}
```

- Using a query

```
// blade.php
<a href="{{ route('admin.articleCreate' , ['article' => $article->YOUR_FIELD]) }}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>

//Controller.php
public function create($article = null)
{
    $article = Article::where('YOUR_FIELD', $article)->firstOrFail();
    return view('admin.article.create', compact('article'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have code

```
return view('admin.article.create', compact('$article'));
```

but need

```
return view('admin.article.create', compact('article'));
```

Comment: Yeah, you right I edit my question but  it doesn't find my create method  if  i put dd(something) in create method  get 404 again I think there is a problem in routes

Comment: can you show me table articles ? which record do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I can see you have mentioned $article in side compact.

Can you please check once, I think the create method should look like this:

```
public function create(Article $article = null)
{
    return view('admin.article.create', compact('article'));
}
```

Comment: You right, I edit  my question it's a question fault. there is my problem